# How to programmatically sync anki flashcard database with local file?

Tags: python, cron, synchronization, anki

I would like to have a script ran by cron or an anki background job that will automatically read in a file (e.g. csv, tsv) containing all my flashcards and update the flashcard database in anki automatically so that i don't have to manually import my flashcards 1000 times a week.

any have any ideas how this can be achieved ?

---

Some interesting links I've came across, including from answers, that might provide a lead towards solutions:

- https://github.com/langfield/ki
- https://github.com/patarapolw/ankisync
- https://github.com/towercity/anki-cli

Comment: there's really not enough here to understand the specific problem you're having; yes, you can use cron or another tool (perhaps a filesystem watcher) to read a file and upload it .. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service and such broad suggestions are off-topic, so to make this a good Question, include what you've done so far (and what _specific_ issues you had, such as an error message)

Comment: @ti7 does anyone know of some library that can communicate with Anki, specically to "import" some `.csv` file containing flashcards. something that can be made into a script that can be run periodically via cron ? doesn't anki have a python api ?

Answer (score 2):

The most robust approach there is so far is to have your collection under git, and use [Ki](https://github.com/langfield/ki) to make Anki behave like a remote repository, so it's very easy to synchronise. The only constraint is the format of your collection. Each card is kept as a single file, and there is no real way around this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of ki, one of the tools you linked! I really appreciate the shout-out @BlackBeans.

It's hard to give you perfect advice without more details about your workflow, but it sounds to me like you've got the source-of-truth for your notes in tabular files, and you import these files into Anki when you've made edits or added new notes.

If this is the case, ki may be what you're looking for. As @BlackBeans mentioned, this tool allows you to convert Anki notes into markdown files, and more generally, handles moving your data from your collection to a git repository, and back.

Basically, if the reason why you've got stuff in tabular files is (1) because you want to version it, (2) because you want to use an external editor, or (3) because your content is generated programmatically, then you might gain some use from using ki.

Feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/langfield/ki/issues/new) describing your use case in detail. I'd love to give you some support in figuring out a good workflow if you think it would be helpful. I am in need of more user feedback at the moment, so you'd be helping me out, too!